# "Slow" exponential decay

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions

I am sorry if mathematics is the wrong place to place this. I simply don't think this is a stack-overflow-question...

I need to price my storage per TB, but i don't want to do this linear. 1TB should be 16\$, going down to 12\$/TB for capacities around 10PB. My current formula (in excel, please excuse!) is `=16*t^-0.03` where t is capacity. This gives me a curve, but it's the "wrong" way around. I'd like it to stay flat for a while and then drop, not drop and stay flat. I tried to google, ask chat-gpt, but i can't figure out what exactly to look for. Could you give me a hint in the right direction?

Thank you so much in advance!
Chris

Comment: A "flat-then-drop" curvecan be obtained with an exponential function, for example in this way $y=a \left( 1 - e^{-c(b-x)}\right)$ for certain positive constants $a,b,c$.